# Is there a metadata database for Go modules?

Tags: database, go, package, repository, metadata

Like npm, there is an index file for all packages in npm - https://replicate.npmjs.com/_all_docs. My question is that is there also such an index file in Go?

Comment: Resource reuqests are off-topic on StackOverflow. But aside from that, what do you want this list _for_? Maybe there's an on-topic question burried in here...

Answer (score 2):

The module index at https://index.golang.org/index is a feed of new module versions fetched through https://proxy.golang.org (documentation for both is [here](https://index.golang.org)). It's the most comprehensive index available, but it is certainly not complete given that use of proxy.golang.org is optional.

You can read all module versions seen by proxy.golang.org in 2K chunks by setting the since query parameter to the max timestamp in the previous chunk.

Use the following code to read the entire feed:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type module struct {
    Path, Version, Timestamp string
}

func chunk(since string) ([]module, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://index.golang.org/index?since=" + since)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    var mods []module
    for dec.More() {
        var mod module
        if err := dec.Decode(&mod); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        mods = append(mods, mod)
    }
    return mods, nil
}

func main() {
    var lastMod module
    for {
        mods, err := chunk(lastMod.Timestamp)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // We are done of there are no results.
        if len(mods) == 0 {
            return
        }

        // Last module in previous chunk can be returned in this chunk.
        if mods[0] == lastMod {
            mods = mods[1:]
        }

        // We are done of there are no results.
        if len(mods) == 0 {
            return
        }

        for _, m := range mods {
            fmt.Println(m.Path, m.Version)
        }

        lastMod = mods[len(mods)-1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [Go.dev](https://go.dev/about) has provided an index file, [Go Module Index](https://index.golang.org/index), but I'm not sure if it contains all of the go modules.

Comment: I think Go Module index doesn't contain all of the modules, much fewer than the total number of this ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you, velkor! Do you know whether who is the provider of this service, how can i collect all the metadata of Golang?

Comment: "I'm not sure if it contains all of the go modules." -- It obviously cannot contain _all_ Go modules. At best, it can contain public Go modules, which it knows about, due to having been requested through the proxy.